# How can I unify width of bars in ggplot2?

Tags: width, bar-chart

I am trying to get a bar-chart by sex using geom_bar(stat="count"), and everything seems fine except for the width of bars, which is inconsistent. For example, if there are no observations in group "F" with the score value of 3 the bar for group "M" becomes twice as big. How do I make it as narrow as the other bars in the example?

```
Score = read.table(header=TRUE,text='score sex
    1 0 F
    2 0 F
    3 0 M
    4 0 M
    5 0 F
    6 1 F
    7 1 M
    8 1 M
    9 2 F
    10 2 M
    11 2 F
    12 3 M
    13 3 M'
    )

b1=ggplot(Score, aes(x=factor(score), fill=sex))+
    geom_bar(stat="count", position=position_dodge())+
    theme_classic()
b1
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding position=position_dodge2(preserve="single") to the geom_bar() line solved it:

```
b1=ggplot(Score, aes(x=factor(score), fill=factor(sex)))+
    geom_bar(stat="count", position=position_dodge2(preserve="single"))+
    theme_classic()
b1
```